# Catch timeout exception

Tags: java, junit

When a TC times out how can I catch the timeout? For example, in the TC below I thought the catch block would execute after the timeout but it doesn't. I want to do same processing after a timeout as if the TC failed with an exception.

```
@Rule 
public Timeout globalTimeout = new Timeout(3600000);

@Test   
public void tc1 throws Exception {  
try {
             //do stuff      
} 
catch (Throwable t) {           
// take screenshot, output results   
}   
}
```

Comment: Cannot you put your processing in a finally block?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says:

> Each test is run in a new thread. If the specified timeout elapses
>   before the test completes, its execution is interrupted via
>   `Thread.interrupt()`. This happens in interruptable I/O and locks, and
>   methods in Object and Thread throwing `InterruptedException`.

It means that `InterruptedException` is thrown incase of timeout. Identify `Throwable` type and handle logging case, as following:

```
@Test   
public void tc1 throws Exception {  
    try {
        //do stuff      
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) {           
        // take screenshot, output results
        if(t instanceof InterruptedException){
            // InterruptedException logging case
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: My catch block doesn't seem to be executed when there's a timeout. Neither is a finally block. The @After method is executed but I'm not sure if there's an easy to check for exceptions/timeouts here.

Comment: This answer's assumption on JUnit's timeout feature is wrong. See https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second rule and chain it with the TimeOut. Use [JUnit's RuleChain](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) for this.

```
@Rule
public final TestRule timeout = RuleChain
    .outerRule(new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
          if (e instanceof TestTimedOutException)
            ;//do your stuff here.
        }
      })
    .around(new Timeout(3600000));
```

Comment: This Rule is executed if the TC passes, fails or timeouts - how do I limit it to only timeouts?

Comment: I changed the example. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to test the exception this way :

```
@Test(expected=TimeoutException.class)
public void tc1{  
 // call your method with parameter so that it will throws a timeoutexception
}
```

It means if the method throws an TimeoutException, then the test will be OK.